# How Vaadin translates &Address to Alt+A using shortcut by a shorthand notation in AbstractField.FocusShortcut?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, vaadin, textfield, shorthand

reading this page of the Book of Vaadin:

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.shortcuts.html

> You can also specify the shortcut by a shorthand notation, where the
>   shortcut key is indicated with an ampersand (&).

```
// A field with Alt+A bound to it, using shorthand notation
TextField address = new TextField("Address (Alt+A)");
address.addShortcutListener(
        new AbstractField.FocusShortcut(address, "&Address"));
```

> This is especially useful for internationalization, so that you can
>   determine the shortcut key from the localized string.

If I add this `address` textfield object to my layout and then I press Alt+A the field is focused.

But how does Vaadin knows that "&Address" is ALT+A??? Does it parses the string internally or compares it with something?

What is this "&Address" `shorthand notation` for keyboard shortcuts? Are there also other shorthand notations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `ShortcutAction` [javadocs](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/ShortcutAction.html#ShortcutAction%28java.lang.String%29):

> Insert one or more modifier characters before the character to use as
>   keycode. E.g "&Save" will make a shortcut responding to ALT-S, "E^xit"
>   will respond to CTRL-X. Multiple modifiers can be used, e.g "&^Delete"
>   will respond to CTRL-ALT-D (the order of the modifier characters is
>   not important).
>
> The modifier characters will be removed from the caption. The modifier
>   character is be escaped by itself: two consecutive characters are
>   turned into the original character w/o the special meaning. E.g
>   "Save&&&close" will respond to ALT-C, and the caption will say
>   "Save&close".

There are three modifier characters: `^` (ctrl), `&` (alt), and `_` (shift). Internally, Vaadin uses regular expressions to parse the shorthand caption, match the modifier characters and build the keyboard shortcuts. You can look at the code [here](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/e88f71dd6d1d7634e3a90a7e53859ff6dc028e21/server/src/com/vaadin/event/ShortcutAction.java#L179).